# how can I get a variable from a lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have a method which looks for animals species in a file and I'd like it to throw an error when a specie don't exist in my database

```java
public void printAnimalFromNames(String... s){
        try (Stream<String> stream = Arrays.stream(s)) {
            stream.forEach(x -> printAnimalPage(AnimalInfo.get(findSpecie(x))));
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("this spiece don't seem to exist");
        }
    }
```

in my catch part I'd like to put the x variable that throw the exeption in my error explanation like

```java
[...]
catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("this spiece "+x+" don't seem to exist");
        }
```

how can I do ?

Comment: This doesn't try to *throw* an error. It tries to *catch* an error. What exactly are you trying to do? What does the `findSpecie()` method do when a specie can't be found? What should happen if 2 different species in the list can't be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to move the `try-catch` inside the body of the lambda, as that's where the lambda parameter, `x`, is in scope:

```
public void printAnimalFromNames(String... s) {
    try (Stream<String> stream = Arrays.stream(s)) {
        stream.forEach(x -> {
            try {
                printAnimalPage(AnimalInfo.get(findSpecie(x)));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("this specie " + x + " don't seem to exist");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Or possibly get rid of the outer `try-catch` which seems to be redundant for closing the stream explicitly.